# Как обновлять html-элемент во время выполнения js-скрипта?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть очень трудоемкая js-функция, которая может выполняться вплоть до нескольких минут. Во время ее выполнения мне нужно обновлять html-элемент, чтобы был виден прогресс выполнения. Выполнять функцию по частям и использовать setTimeout не вариант, так как разбить функцию на части не представляется возможным.

Comment: Можно вынести долгий синхронный скрипт в воркер... https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Добавьте код, пожалуйста, без него нельзя будет помочь вам.

Comment: @ksa Из вашей ссылки: `Например, вы не можете прямо манипулировать DOM внутри worker-а`, из вопроса: `Во время ее выполнения мне нужно обновлять html-элемент`

Comment: @ΝNL993, воркер может отправлять сообщения "основному" срипту - вот он-то и будет "рисовать" прогресс.

Comment: @ksa как он поможет показывать оставшееся время выполнения у скрипта? (Без шуток, интересно)

Comment: @ΝNL993, если ты уже делал отображение прогресса в вэбе - все будет аналогично. В процессе выполнения задания воркер может отсылать те же проценты (10%, 20% и т.д.), а "слушатель" в основном скрипте может выполнять отображение этого прогресса...

Comment: @ksa вопрос в том откуда он будет получать эти проценты?

Comment: К счастью, получить процент выполнения проблем нет. Прочитал статью, кажется, что воркер - именно то что нужно. Попробую разобраться и отпишу

Comment: @ΝNL993, это не мой алгоритм... Откуда мне знать как ТС собирается рассчитывать прогресс выполнения того скрипта? Если он как-то собрался его считать - значит посчитать его можно. Была лишь проблема в "освобождении" основного процесса от долгого и синхронного кода.

Comment: @ksa погодите... Вопрос разве не был как раз таки про прогресс, а не про "освобождение"?

Comment: @ΝNL993, тогда мы с тобой по разному читаем вопрос ТСа... Даже сам `Ace Ace` тебе уже ответил выше за меня.

Comment: @ksa хе-хе, но по моему вы просто упустили основной вопрос (он в заголовке) ;)

Comment: @ΝNL993, как скажешь, как скажешь... Я все никак за тобой не успеваю...

Comment: @ksa Вчера забыл отписаться. Пришлось немного разобраться с воркером и как правильно передавать объекты класса. Все получилось. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @AceAce, вот и чудненько.